# Amazon EC2 instance for Ruby on Rails + Thin + Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, nginx

I've been looking for an AMI that has basically an updated version of ruby gems, thin and nginx and mysql installed.

EC2onRails seems to be left alone now since Paul decided to leave the project.

If you were to deploy your Rails App in the cloud, what are your benchmarks? Recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find good enough an answer to this question so finally went for deploying ruby 1.9.2 and Rails3 from scratch as mentioned here .. http://blog.enbake.com/setting-up-rails-3-stack-on-an-amazon-ec2-instance/

Answer (score 1):

This may be a good head start
http://thecloudmarket.com/tag/rails